# Вывод из базы MySQL

Tags: структуры-данных, база-данных, php, постраничный-вывод, mysql

Всем привет, есть 4 таблицы в MySQL:

1. Таблица марка `idmarka, marka_name`.
2. Таблица модель `idmodel, idmarka, model_name`.
3. Таблица группа товара `idgroup, name_group`.
4. Таблица товара `idtovar, idgroup, op_tovar, ob_tovar, pro_tovar`.
5. Таблица переменные `idmarka, idmodel, idgroup, idtovar`.

Можно ли в таблице переменные заложить айдишники всех таблиц для вывода каталога? 
Получится примерно массив такой:

```
1,2,3,2
1,4,5,10
и тд
```

И ещё вопрос, какого типа данных должна быть таблица переменные, для того чтоб в неё можно было записать несколько айдишников одинаковых?

И прошу помощи, если это возможно, написать запрос из базы, заранее спасибо!!!

Нужно вывести меню в виде древовидного. 
Пример:

```
MAN
----TGA 
----FH8
      |_____Фильтры
      |_____КПП
```

Comment: @Владимир Бельков, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Владимир Бельков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для твоей цели не нужно присваивать айдишники в таблице переменные, так как эта таблица играет роль связывающей, и с помощью неё ты можешь извлекать нужное из других. В данном случае можно использовать INNER JOIN, о том, что это такое, прочитать уже нужно в справке. И еще имена таблиц кириллистическими символами никогда не называются.

Даю наводку на решение, запрос нужно будет адаптировать под свои нужды:

```
SELECT marka.marka_name, group.name_group, tovar.op_tovar FROM `марка` AS marka INNER JOIN `переменные` AS variables ON  marka.idmarka = variables.idmarka INNER JOIN `группа товара` AS group ON group.idgroup = variables.idgroup INNER JOIN `Таблица товара` AS tovar ON tovar.idtovar = variables.idtovar;
```

Примерно так это выглядит, адаптируй под себя и используй.

Comment: Спасибо большое,  а то начал думать через запрос Json, были варианты связать переменные,  но вы помогли встать на путь иной!!!!